# Number of search results at GitHub changes drastically from search to search

Tags: github, github-api-v3

I'm trying the following simple query: [github.com/search?l=Gradle&q="android.support.test"&type=Code](https://github.com/search?l=Gradle&q=%22android.support.test%22&type=Code)

But every time I run it I get a different number of total search results, varying from 200k results up to 700k.

What's going on here? Is there a way to obtain an exact result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize there is a question mark icon which when clicked shows the following text:

> This search took too long to finish; some results may not be shown.

Thus, GitHub is cutting short the search query.